# Error while building Boost.Asio Tutorial with CMake

Tags: ubuntu, boost, cmake, boost-asio

#### Problem

I was trying to use Boost.Asio 1.58 with the [code on this tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime2.html) on Ubuntu 16.04.

Boost is installed on `usr/include/boost`, was installed with OpenCV Package.

And tried to build with Cmake, the CMakeLists.txt is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)

project(server)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)
find_package(Boost 1.58 REQUIRED)
if(Boost_FOUND)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
add_executable(server server.cpp)
target_link_libraries(server ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY})
end if()
```

> Tried to change CMakeLists.txt in many ways, however it didn't work.
>   Already used Cmake to build with another library (PCL), however, now
>   CMAKE stopped. And is giving this error...

Commands:

```
cd
cd tests
mkdir daytimeservertcp
cd daytimeservertcp
sudo nano server.cpp `#paste code, ctrl+x , y , enter` \
sudo nano CMakeLists.txt
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
```

server.cpp is the file with the code from the tutorial and CMakeLists.txt was refered before.

Also tried `cmake -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/ssl -DOPENSSL_LIBRARIES=/usr/local/ssl/lib` with the same error.

However, when i run `cmake ..` it shows this error:

> cmake: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

#### Checks

Checking openssl version:

```
openssl version -v
OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017)
```

`ldd`:

for version 1.0.2:

```
ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.2
ldd: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.2: No such file or directory
```

for version 1.0.0

```
ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffefa110000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f70e8ec2000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f70e8af8000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f70e88f3000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055996589f000)
```

for version 1.1 It is on a different local:

```
ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl*
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl3.so:
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff7367d000)
    libnss3.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss3.so (0x00007fb35bb56000)
    libnssutil3.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnssutil3.so (0x00007fb35b929000)
    libplc4.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplc4.so (0x00007fb35b723000)
    libnspr4.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnspr4.so (0x00007fb35b4e4000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fb35b2c7000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fb35aefc000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fb35ace2000)
    libplds4.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplds4.so (0x00007fb35aade000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fb35a8d9000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fb35a6d1000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055fb5dcb2000)
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.a:
    not a dynamic executable
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so:
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc8b7e8000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f69b43e4000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f69b41c7000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f69b3dfc000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f69b3bf8000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055bacc56a000)
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1:
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff117e5000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f0e705f4000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0e703d7000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0e7000c000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f0e6fe08000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055d33980f000)
```

When trying to install libssl 1.0.2:

```
 sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.2 libssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libssl1.0.2 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libssl1.0.2' has no installation candidate
```

So [this link](https://www.miguelvallejo.com/tag/installing-openssl-1-0-2g-on-ubuntu/) was used.

#### Question

*How do i build it correctly?*

Am i linking incorrectly? Where do i change to load version 1.0.0 and not 1.0.2?

p.s.: Ubuntu Newbie here

Comment: If the error occurs when you run `cmake ..`, then you didn't even begin building your application, rather CMake seems to fail while generating the project (makefiles or whatever else you may be using). Please, provide more context for the error message.

Comment: The exact problem is in the error message you quote: cmake is unable to find `libssl.so.1.0.2`. Do you have libssl installed?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/77256/i-want-to-install-libssl-0-9-8

Comment: Yeah, my version is newer: 1.1.0, so i tried to install 1.0.2 with [this link](https://www.miguelvallejo.com/tag/installing-openssl-1-0-2g-on-ubuntu/). However, when i use the command: `openssl version -v` The output is: `OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017)`. And older builds made with CMake stopped working and are giving this error, CMake was working until today.

Comment: @danieltakeshi Don't mess around with your system like that. There is a reason Linux distros come with a package manager that has build in dependency checks. If you just start installing conflicting versions of libraries manually on the system you should not be surprised if things start breaking down. Either stick with the dependency manager, or make sure that you carefully set up an isolated build environment that it is self-consistent. Note that doing the latter is a non-trivial task and usually not one that is solved by trial-and-error.

Comment: Thanks all for advice, I reinstalled everything and Cmake is working now. However, I don't know what made it stop. Since i didn't make any big change that i am aware of. Only after it stopped.